# In JavaScript, what is the difference between var a=5. and var a=5?

Tags: javascript

Such as the Title Description

In JavaScript, what is the difference between var a=5. and var a=5?

```
typeof(5.)  //return number

typeof(5)  //return number
```

Comment: I don't see any difference! Are you talking about that `.`?

Comment: There is no difference, all numbers are floats in javascript.

4.3.20 Number Type: The type Number is a set of values representing numbers. In ECMAScript, the set of values represents the doubleprecision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values including the special “Not-a-Number” (NaN) values, positive infinity, and negative infinity.

Comment: Integers? They don't exist in JavaScript. They are all doubles.

Answer (score 8):

In javascript floating point numbers are also considered as number so `typeof(5.)` is equal to `typeof(5.0)` which returns number.